# Single application with customized data model for different customers

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

I am writing an application which should be customized for different customers. The main parts will stay same but some behavior will slightly differ. It should also have different data fields in forms - again, the main structure will be the same, just some extra input fields. I want to do it with minimal effort. The application is developed using Xamarin Forms and EF Core and each client will have its own version deployed on its own tablet.

My question is what is the best way how to do such application. I am planning to create specific assembly for each customer which will implement the behavior customization. Then inject those classes to the main application through Autofac. But I am not sure about the data model - because EF Core needs those classes in the main assembly. I thought about #define for each customer and #ifdefs in the data models, but that would clutter the source very soon. And there is also question how to perform migrations? I thought about creating a generic Entity "ExtendedProperty" which could add new properties to each entity. This way, the data model would be the same for each customer (containing common properties) and new properties could be added without problems.

The other thing is how to customize the Xamarin Forms views to display the different fields. I would like to avoid implementing different views from scratch for each customer. I can see implementing dynamic form which would read properties of the data model through reflection and dynamically create fields. Or again,
replace small parts of the view by its customized counterpart from the customization assembly.

What is the best way to create such application?

Comment: Take a look to [this article by XamlGirl](https://xamgirl.com/white-labeling-in-xamarin-forms-applications/) it's seems to be exactly what you need

Comment: @FabriBertani Do you consider to use different [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating) for different customers?

Comment: @FabriBertani this article really does bring a lot of insight into this issue. Thank you for that. It just doesn't tackle the issue with different data models.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Yeah, DataTemplates could solve the issue with different views. Why didn't I think about that... :) So each Customer project could register its own DataTemplate in the container.

Comment: @FilipMestanek yes, you can try to use it, hope it can solve your problem.